# Obtain direct instance methods defined on a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to get all the methods that are defined **directly** on the class

Here is what I currently do:

```
class Mine
  def immediate
  end

  (instance_methods - ancestors.second.instance_methods)
  # [:immediate]
end
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Mine.instance_methods false
```

does this look good? or how do you like to write it? something like Mine.my_instance_methods? :)

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thanks. Didn't realise `instance_methods` has 1 argument called `include_super=true` :)

Comment: perhaps ... least surprise principle :)